# Is $\{X(A): A \in F\}$ a $\sigma-$field?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am currently working on the following problem for my measure theory course and do not believe my reasoning for a contradiction is correct.

> Let $(\Omega,F,P)$ be a probability space and $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable. Is $\{X(A): A \in F\}$ a $\sigma-$field?

I figured it might be easiest to answer this question with an example. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = x^2$. As we can see, $f(\mathbb{R}) = [0,\infty) \in \{X(A): A \in F\}$. However if we take the compliment of $[0,\infty)$ we get $(-\infty,0)$ which is not the image of any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ under $f$ since any subset (that has an image under $f$) we pick will be contained in $[0,\infty)$.

This last sentence is where I am a little shaky, I don't think my reasoning entirely makes sense. Any tips or feedback is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Your example is correct. :)

Comment: @ActuallyFritz - Thats good to hear. Is my wording okay as well? The sentence following the last, I was thinking of just writing "hence, a contradiction" if everything else is okay.

Comment: I would write something like hence $X(F)$ is not a $\sigma-$field for all measurable functions $X$ (btw, note that your function is a measurable function rather than a random variable since you haven't defined your probability space; however, your argument works for the standard measure space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \lambda)$).